# jQuery select element fail

Tags: php, jquery, select

This error in Firebug: `missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error] $('select > option:contains('100')').attr('selected',true);`

```
$('select > option:contains('100')').attr('selected',true);
```

No idea why?? i'm trying to set 100 as the selected option in a PHP built select element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('select > option:contains(\'100\')').attr('selected',true);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Not that i dont believe you but how did that fix it?

Comment: a parser thinks you closed the string once it encounters the second ', as a result it looks for either a comma or close bracket - which is what you can see from the error message, because it encounters the value 100. so you need to let the parser know that your quote is intended to be part of the string itself by backslashing (aka escaping) it