# How to select an element value with jquery?

Tags: jquery-selectors

## Question

> **How can we apply a jQuery selector to return elements based on their HTML value?**

I know there must be many ways to do this, but I wonder if there's any short and good way to do it.

Picture this HTML:

```
<element>valuable</element>
```

I'd want a jQuery like this:

```
$('element[value="valuable"]').doSomething();
```

### Bad Solutions

The way I've solved this for now is by changing the HTML into this:

```
<element value="valuable">valuable</element>
```

Sure I could also solve this following the same logic and doing it on jQuery:

```
$('element').each(function(i){$(this).attr("value",$(this).html());});
```

I don't know which one is worst!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally [found it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671734/jquery-select-element-fail/4671743#4671743)... I rushed too much ahead of myself before doing my last search method: *asking a question*. I usually type the title, look at the suggestions already posted, try modifying the title, look again... This time I already wrote the answer and forgot to look there, and when I pressed "post" I remembered to go and try it.

So the answer I was looking for would be:

```
$('element:contains("valuable")').doSomething();
```

Comment: @asawayer my mistake. I posted fast before bringing trouble to someone. Thanks for the warning! :)